# Getting price difference between two dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table where once a day/hour lines are added that contain the product ID, price, name and time at which the line was added.

```
CREATE TABLE products 
(
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL,
    price double precision NOT NULL,
    checked_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

The data in the `products` table looks like this:

| id | product_id | title | price | checked_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1000** | **Watermelon** | **50** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| **2** | **2000** | **Apple** | **30** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| **3** | **3000** | **Pear** | **20** | **2022-07-19 10:00:00** |
| 4 | 1000 | Watermelon | 100 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 2000 | Apple | 50 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| 6 | 3000 | Pear | 35 | 2022-07-20 10:00:00 |
| **7** | **1000** | **Watermelon** | **150** | **2022-07-21 10:00:00** |
| **8** | **2000** | **Apple** | **50** | **2022-07-21 10:00:00** |
| **9** | **3000** | **Pear** | **60** | **2022-07-21 10:00:00** |

I need to pass a date range (for example, from 2022-07-19 to 2022-07-21) and get the difference in prices of all unique products, that is, the answer should be like this:

| product_id | title | price_difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Watermelon | 100 |
| 2000 | Apple | 20 |
| 3000 | Pear | 40 |

I only figured out the very beginning, where I need to get the ID of all unique products in the table using `DISTINCT`. Next, I need to find the rows that are closest to the date range. And finally find the difference in the price of each product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT product_id, title,
       MAX(price) FILTER (WHERE checked_at::date = '2022-07-21') -
       MAX(price) FILTER (WHERE checked_at::date = '2022-07-19') AS price_difference
FROM products
GROUP BY product_id, title
ORDER BY product_id;
```

Comment: Really useful. I'd not seen the FILTER clause used before. Do you have any recommended reading to learn more about that?

Comment: @FlexYourData `FILTER` is new as of Postgres 9.6 or thereabouts.  Just check the docs for it, or find a decent tutorial site.